# xml how to replace [element] in string mysql xslt xpath?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

hi guys im having trouble working out what script i can use to replace part of a string in xml, data for example here is the xml

```
<product>
<image>
path/to/image.jpg
</image>
<url>
http://website.com/imformation?x=[id]&y=[op]
</url>
<price>
99.99
</price>
</product>
```

all this information would be imported into a datebase but im a bit confused on how i can replace the elements in the url  i know how i can edit the nodes and such using xslt and xpath but im not sure how i can replace the [id] ive searched everywhere but cant for the life of me find an explanation on how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all using XSLT.

### XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="replacedURL">
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/product/url/text()"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'[id]'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'Hello'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$replacedURL"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="by"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above XSLT, I have used a template called **"string-replace-all"**. This template will replace all the matches to the required value.

### Template:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

### HOW TO CALL THE TEMPLATE?

```
<xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/product/url/text()"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'[id]'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'Hello'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Here:

- `text` : http://website.com/imformation?x=[id]&y=[op]
- `replace` : [id]
- `by` : Hello

### OUTPUT:

```
http://website.com/imformation?x=Hello&y=[op]
```

Do the same for `[op]` too.

Comment: thanks for that explanation it helped but i still have a problem the original xml is half gig when i try transforming using eclipse it goes through it but at the end i just get an xml header no nodes and the first url printed with the field replaced but theres no more data and all the nodes have gone could this be caused by the size of the file ?